# How to make a g element in an SVG clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I understand that it is a grouping for transformations. I have also looked through the documentation and have found nothing regarding this, but was wondering whether it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Fill it with a `<rect width="whatever the <g> width is" height="whatever the <g> height is"/>` and make the `<rect>` clickable. The rect can be transparent check out the [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property for how to configure clicability of the `<rect>`.

You can find the `<g>` height and width by calling getBBox.

Comment: That fills the entire svg with a rect.

Answer (score 1):

Assign id to  element, and listener.
Ex.

```
<g id="clickg"><circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/><g>

$("#clickg").on("click",function () {
    alert("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Super old question but it helped me out so I want to expand on one of the answers with a little more of a step-by-step guide and some more details. This is the method I made when my group was several disconnected items and I wanted the whole area including the blank areas in between to be clickable.

1. Get the x/y/width/height of the `<g>` element, you can do this easily in chrome dev tools by selecting the `<g>` element and entering `$0.getBBox()` in the console.
2. Create a new element as a child of your `<g>` like so: `<rect x="TODO" y="TODO" width="TODO" height="TODO" style="pointer-events: all" />`
3. Replace the TODO above with the info from `getBBox`