# :hover on SVG g element only applies when path inside of g is also hovered

Tags: css, svg

I just got an SVG and added a CSS class to some g elements inside of it to style them on hover. But the hover pseudo-selector only applies if a path element inside of the g is also hovered. How can I solve this to make hover apply also when just the g background is hovered? Unfortunately I cannot show you the code for legal reasons.

Comment: You can show us code that **demonstrates** the issue...just redact anything confidential.

Comment: I will use the approach from Robert's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198381/how-to-make-a-g-element-in-an-svg-clickable

Comment: add some code to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var container = $('.svgcontainer');
    var words = $('.words-as-g-in-container');
    words.each(function (i, el) {
        var rect = el.getBBox();
        var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        var help = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
        help.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', rect.x);
        help.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', rect.y);
        help.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', rect.height);
        help.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', rect.width);
        help.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'transparent');
        el.appendChild(help);

    });
    words.hover(function () {
        container.addClass('svgcontainer--with-hover');
    }, function () {
        container.removeClass('svgcontainer--with-hover');
    });
```